# How to use global log4j.xml

Tags: java, log4j

I have a Java library which uses log4j. The library itself contains only a log4j.property file which has the following contents:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
```

The library is used by another application, which has its own global log4j.xml.

I put lines like this in the global log4j.xml:

```
<logger name="com.my.package">
    <level value="info"/>
</logger>
```

However, none of the logs are shown in the log.

What's going wrong here?

Many thanks.

Comment: afaik , you tell which config file ure gonna use , when u instantiate the logger , so theres no problem how many libraries use the same library

Answer (score 1):

2 things I can think of:

1. The log4j.xml file is not on the class path.
2. You are writing DEBUG messages and the logger is set to INFO.